# How can I make the battery icon appear in my gnome-3 panel only when charging or discharging?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, power-management, battery, gsettings

I am using ubuntu 11.10. There was an option for the same in 11.04.

I found a suggestion listed [here](http://jfsaucier.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/gnome-3/). Unfortunately, it does'nt work.

> $ GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.power-manager
>   icon-policy charge 
> No such key 'icon-policy'

Answer (score 1):

Manually creating icon-policy key & setting it to "charge" might help, however I did it from terminal & it worked fine for me(both in gnome-shell & fallback mode).

Run update manager & make sure you have latest updates.Disable any extension(if you have any) related to power or battery.Then open terminal & run following command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.power-manager icon-policy
```

it should return something like these:

```
:~$ gsettings range org.gnome.power-manager icon-policy
enum
'present'
'charge'
'low'
'critical'
'never'
```

Now set the icon policy to charge:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.power-manager icon-policy charge
```

Restart gnome-shell.

Done!

Does this help?

---

**Update:** ***This above method only works with gnome 3.1.3 or less***.

Unfortunately in latest gnome  this isn't possible any more. "`org.gnome.power-manager icon-policy`" has been removed in GNOME 3.2, as gnome-power-manager code has been moved to `gnome-settings-daemon`, where there is no key to configure this. See this bug report([bug 655298](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=655298)).

If you want to hide battery icon in gnome shell, see this post:
[how to remove battery indicator in gnome-shell?](http://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/460/how-to-remove-battery-indicator-in-gnome-shell)

On Unity, support for hiding of icon and settings has been added with indicator-power - 1.90-0ubuntu1 ([bug 811769](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power/+bug/811769)).

Comment: @Kurshid, How can I create the key manually??

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that this isn't possible any more with Gnome 3.2. See the update.